# Sorting entries from a text file

Tags: php, sorting

This piece of code displays the latest 50 entries in a file:

```
 $file = file("sample.txt");
 for ($i = max(0, count($file)-50); $i < count($file); $i++) {
   echo $file[$i] . "\n";
 }
```

Results on a file with 1000 entries display the oldest entries on top and the newest ones at the bottom:

```
950
951
952
...
998
999
1000
```

How can I change the order so that the newest entries are on top
and the older ones below?

```
1000
999
998
...
952
951
950
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`$file = file("sample.txt");
 for ($i = count($file)-1; $i >= max(0, count($file)-50); $i--) {
 echo $file[$i] . "\n";
 }`

It is basicly starting from the last line of the file and counting back.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the sort function. See this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php